# json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given, how to update all row (specific column)

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am trying to create a sorting system (drag and drop ) . But the problem is it's getting array while it requires string. my code in the controller is :

```
public function sort(Request $request){
 
  $imageids = request()->input("imageids");

  $data = json_decode($imageids,true);
  
    if (is_array($data)) {
        foreach ($data as $value) {
            $taskItem = Task::find($value['id']);
            $taskItem->priority = $value['priority'];
            
            $taskItem->save();
        }
    } else {
        $taskItem = Task::find(request()->input("id"));
        $taskItem->priority = request()->input("priority");
         
        $taskItem->save();
    }
     
}
```

Comment: it may be worth moving your `is_array()` check to above the `json_decode` and then handling it in that fashion. Otherwise you'll need to change the way this page is "posted" to in order to post as a json string rather than as an array...

Comment: still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

your `request()->input("imageids")` is returned array, so you don't need `json_decode`. Another way use condition like below:

```
if(is_string($imageids))
{
  $data = json_decode($imageids,true);
}
else
{
  $data = $imageids;

}
```

Comment: now it's saying "Creating default object from empty value"

Comment: I in fact need the array, so that I can update all rows